# To get the module names in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to get the application module name I have installed in Blackberry, just like "Messages","Contacts" etc. How can i get this module's names which are running now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following code snippet:

```java
//get the ApplicationManager
ApplicationManager appMan = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();

//grab the running applications
ApplicationDescriptor[] appDes = appMan.getVisibleApplications();

int size = appDes.length;
for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    String moduleName = appDes[i].getModuleName();
    String name = appDes[i].getName();
    // other codes....
}
```

Also read the API documentation for following classes:

- [ApplicationManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationManager.html)
- [ApplicationDescriptor](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationDescriptor.html)
- [CodeModuleGroupManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CodeModuleGroupManager.html)
- [CodeModuleGroup](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CodeModuleGroup.html)

Comment: But this will return me the string value like "net_rim_bb_messaging_app".

Comment: what about appDes[i].getName()?

Comment: Now i need something different. Suppose i am clicking one application icon in the phone(like "Messages"). How can i get that application name value which i clicked??

Comment: good question, but I didn't try this earlier. AFAIK we can catch events generated by "Cancel", "Call", "Menu" and "Back" key press while application is in background, but don't think it will be helpful in this case.

Comment: Even for some icon like "Browser", "Media", we can not get the application name using appDes[i].getName(). How can i get those names?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current applications module name or handle by using this line:

```
String name = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor().getModuleName();
```

This returns the string of the module handle of this application. Or by using

```
int handle = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor().getModuleHandle();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Application Version (programatically) you can use:

net.rim.device.api.system.DeviceInfo.getSoftwareVersion()