# Get all the installed applications on device and show is list filed

Tags: java, list, blackberry

I have got the all installed apps from the device by using this code. I need to know whether the list I posted contains only applications or it's a combination of applications and libraries.

If it contains libraries, then how would I know which are applications and which are libraries? I mean I only want to show the application which the user can launch from the Home screen.

I am working on 5 OS. Here is my code to get the installed apps and my output.

```
CodeModuleGroup[] codeModuleGroups = CodeModuleGroupManager.loadAll();
            System.out.println(" CodeModuleGroup  "+ codeModuleGroups.length);  
            for (int i=0; i<codeModuleGroups.length;i++) {
                System.out.println(" getFriendlyName  "+ codeModuleGroups[i].getFriendlyName());  
                System.out.println(" \n");  
                
            }
    CodeModuleGroup  104
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Documents To Go
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Email Setup library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Texas Hold'Em King 2
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Sudoku
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Klondike
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Social Feeds
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  eBay
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry Messenger
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Sunrays
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry Identity
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Facebook
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry Podcasts
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry 6.0.0 Core Applications
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Email Setup
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  YouTube
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry API Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry Crypto Applications API Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry Crypto Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry CMS Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  French
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Spanish
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  English UK
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  German
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry PGP Key Store Browser Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry Certificate Key Store Browser Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry Key Store Browser Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  GSA CAC Smart Card Driver Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry Full Fast Predictive Input Method Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Japanese Characters and Font Support
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Italian
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Indic Characters and Font Support
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Indonesian
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Hindi Localization
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Hindi
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Simplified Stroke IM Linguistic Data Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Simplified Chinese Characters and Font Support
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Simplified Localization Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Simplified Input Method Default Resource Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Stroke Input Method Core Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Phonetic Input Method Core Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Hanwang key Input Method Core Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Default Resource Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Input Method Core Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Hindi Localization
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Vietnamese
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Thai Characters and Font Support
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Thai
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Korean Characters and Font Support
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Korean
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Traditional Pinyin Input Method
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Traditional CangJie Input Method
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese BoPoMoFo Input Method
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Traditional Chinese Characters and Font Support
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Traditional Localization Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Traditional IM Linguistic Data Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese HongKong Input Method Default Resource Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese WubiHua Input Method
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Simplified Pinyin Resources Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Simplified Pinyin IM Linguistic Data Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Pinyin Input Method
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Simplified CangJie Input Method
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry Application Center
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Word Mole
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BrickBreaker
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry XML Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry S/MIME Email Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry PGP Email Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry Secure Email Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  SafeNet 330 Smart Card Driver Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  PIV Smart Card Driver Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry PGP Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  microSD Smart Card Reader
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry X.509 LDAP Browser
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry PGP LDAP Browser
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry LDAP Browser Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Stroke Input Method
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry Protect
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Twitter
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Enhanced Gmail Plug-in
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Help
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Browser
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry Maps
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry 6.0.0 System Software
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Tasks
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Phone
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Password Keeper
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  MemoPad
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  German Language Support
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry ECMAScript Library
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Traditional Chinese Language Support
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Chinese Language Support
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Thai Language Support
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Korean Language Support
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Italian Language Support
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Indonesian Language Support
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  French Language Support
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Spanish Language Support
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  English UK Language Support
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry Wallet
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Wireless Music Sync
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  net_rim_bb_medialoader_ringtones_480x360_03_b
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Lock
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  Sai Vahini
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0]  getFriendlyName  BlackBerry App World
```

Comment: So the answer given here:  http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/get-all-the-installed-applications-on-device-and-show-is-list/m-p/2619385#M223486m which suggests the use of the flags associated with a CodeModuleGroup does not help?

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469795/to-get-the-module-names-in-blackberry and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372791/get-a-list-of-all-installed-applications-on-blackberry

Comment: @MisterSmith - I suggested that in the BB Forum Thread, but OP wanted applications that were not currently active as well as those that were.

Comment: i just want to show that installed apps,
which the user can see and can able to launch from the Home Screen ?
i have read the FLAG_LIBRARY  doc.
and i try to use it with CodeModuleGroup, but not getting success, any help on it. ??
and one thing i have to ask is that can we seprate the apps from the library's , i mean we can show the insatlled apps which user can able to launch from Home Screen in one list filed and the other Core library's or apps in differnt List filed , if we are not able to filter the list in  my first question. ?